# Is there a Textmate equivalent of "Format indenting of selected code" in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: ide, textmate, text-editor, sublimetext, sublimetext2

In Textmate, the keyboard shortcut <kbd>⌘⌥[</kbd> properly indents all the nesting on selected code.

Is there a similar option in Sublime Text 2? It's the only thing holding me back from switching and I've checked all documentation to try and find something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if Sublime Text 2 has a generic code formatter, but there are a lot of really good packages out there that will provide various formatting for different languages.

Take a look at Package Control (used to manage plugins for Sublime).
http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/community

For formatting Ruby there's a pretty good package called BeautifyRuby. https://github.com/CraigWilliams/BeautifyRuby

Answer (score 2):

What you are actually looking for is "reindent". It's under the Edit -> Line -> Reindent option. Strangely enough it's not bound to a keystroke. Simply installing code syntax packages will not cause them to apply the formatting to existing code.